# Regex for URLs shows ".finance" as invalid/error

Tags: regex, laravel

I got this regex for my laravel URL validator and if i put a ".finance" domain it shows it's against the regex. What is wrong? All other tested domain endings work so far.

```
$regex = '/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/';
```

Comment: increase 5 in `{2,5}` `finance` is 7 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `[a-z]{2,5}` with `[a-z]{2,}` to allow any two or more letters in the TLD.

Remove `{1}`, these are always unnecessary.

`(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?` is way to repeptitive, shorten it with optional groups / chars to `(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?`.

Use

```php
/^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/LLUPd4/1/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      www                      'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z0-9]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-.]                     any character of: '-', '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]{2,}                any character of: 'a' to 'z' (at least 2
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{1,5}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1
                             and 5 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```